# Attempting to Center Text Under Button - Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface, android-manifest

I'm attempting to center some text underneath a button but it is appearing on top of the button for some reason. Any suggestions? I'm really not sure what might be causing this.

I can upload a screen shot if necessary.

SOURCE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emblem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_align="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/start_text2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_align` doesn't look like a valid attribute, can you try removing that line?

Comment: Ya, `android:layout_align` only accepts values like `center_vertical` etc. Remove that and you should be good.

Comment: Also, you set a `layout_weight` on your `View` tag. This tag can only be used on children of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: plz provide the screenshot.

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/go_button"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" /> try this.

Answer (score 1):

just changed your code a bit, hope it works for you

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/go_button" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add gravity to get the text centered:

```
        <TextView android:id="@+id/text" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/go_button" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```